# How to write internal URLs in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am testing the site on local server is address  `my.internal/test.php`

WHich is working fine in browser

But when i do this , the nothing happens

```
$(function() {

        $.get("my.internal/test.php", function(data){
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            alert('hello')  ;
        });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you specify an absolute or a relative address.
If you pass an absolute one, you have to write the full URL, i.e. including the protocol:

```
$(function() { 

        $.get("http://my.internal/test.php", function(data){ 
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data); 
            alert('hello')  ; 
        }); 

});
```

You could also use this URL:

```
/test.php
```